# X11VNC Create X Server On N Display

Tags: x11, display, x11vnc

I want to create a X11 display with X11VNC on specific display without resorting to -env X11VNC_CREATE_STARTING_DISPLAY_NUMBER=31, rather I want to specify N display and have it created appropriately. If the environment variable set above is all X11VNC has, then that's fine though seems impractical because it might work on 31, 32, 33, etc without definitively saying it'll be created on 31.

Here's my shell script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

export DISPLAY=:3

Xvfb $DISPLAY -screen 0 1280x1024x24 &
x11vnc -display $DISPLAY -forever -rfbport 5903 -env X11VNC_CREATE_STARTING_DISPLAY_NUMBER=31 -create
```

The command to my understanding knowledge is taking 3 and mapping it to 31, I would like 31 to be hard coded to always start on 31 and if an error occurs, so what.